# Is it okay to mark @Input() as private or readonly?

Tags: angular, typescript

Let's say, in an Angular component, I receive a parameter from its parent.

```js
export class SomethingComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() delay: number;
}
```

Is it good practice, acceptable, or better to mark it as `private` or `readonly`?

```js
export class SomethingComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() private readonly delay: number;
}
```

What's the technical difference?

Comment: I don’t think you can mark it as private or read only, as an input is by definition neither of those things. The dev server might accept it but building for prod should throw an error at you.

Comment: private is only a compile-time construct - it cannot be enforced at runtime plus having a private property with an @Input decorator shouldn't have any effect in runtime. This modifier is virtual and it's gone after TypeScript to JavaScript compilation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a purely technical standpoint, neither actually matter at runtime as both do not exist in Javascript. These constructs are only present in Typescript to aid the developers.

Here's some example Typescript:

```
class Car {
    private ownerName: string;
    readonly vehicleIdNumber: string;
    mileage: number;
}

let car = new Car();

//typescript compilation error: 
//  Property 'ownerName' is private and only accessible within class 'Car'.
car.ownerName = "test";

//typescript compilation error: 
//  Cannot assign to 'vehicleIdNumber' because it is a read-only property.
car.vehicleIdNumber = "543798";

//No error here!
car.mileage = 10000;
```

When this is compiled to Javascript, those access modifiers go away and you're free to use those attributes are you wish. Here's what the resulting Javascript would look like.

```
class Car {
}

let car = new Car();
car.ownerName = "test";
car.vehicleIdNumber = "543798";
car.mileage = 10000;
```

From Angulars perspective, `private` or `readonly` on an `@Input()` property doesn't really make sense.

Private members are typically only accessible within the body of the class it's declared in. Since you're accessing them outside the class in another components template, you're violating this rule.

Readonly members are typically not allowed to be assigned to after the constructor exits, and in Angular the `@Input()` attributes are actually set *after* the constructor but *before* `ngOnInit()`.

Answer (score 1):

The `private` keyword is just meant to state an intention at compile time as a way to encapsulate there is no difference at runtime. And the conveyed intention is that the said variable or property or method should not be accessed by any other class or component. From a security point of view there is no inherent benefit to doing this.

So answering your question, it is okay to mark it as private as long as your intent is to signal for coder's understanding while they are trying to access it from another place in application.